# MapLoader / MapStore from Hazelcast C# Client

Tags: hazelcast

I can implement MapLoader/MapStore using Hazelcast Java client. But, this is not available in Hazelcast-csharp client API. I need to know whether this feature is available, then how to access it or else will it be available in upcoming releases of Hazelcast. Currently am using Hazelcast-3.6.3.dll

Comment: dear Raji. Kindly accept the answer if you're satisfied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MapLoader / MapStore is a **cluster side component**. It runs within cluster.

You can't implement it with Java or csharp **clients**, only on member/node side (Java API only).

Thanks

Comment: What i understood from your answer is i need to have custom jar containing the logic for load/store from/to the persistence storage which will be added to the lib path of member/node and then i will configure that class to the map which is under policy eviction. Am i right? Vik Gamov.

Comment: Precisely, dear sir! Except, you need configure this class under map-store section of config http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.6/manual/html-single/index.html#loading-and-storing-persistent-data

Comment: Thanks for your answer and immediate reply Vik Gamov.

Comment: Let me know if you have any questions. Otherwise, please consider my answer as correct one. Thanks